# Find out "flattened index" from "stacked index" of an Array

Tags: ruby, math, matrix

I'm trying to come up with an equation to mathematically determine the "flattened index" of an array from the "stacked index."  Observe the following example in Ruby.

```
matx = [[[ 1, 2, 3, 4],
         [ 5, 6, 7, 8]],

        [[ 9,10,11,12],
         [13,14,15,16]]]
```

In this example, `matx` is a three dimensional matrix, and the element `7` is located at `matx[0][1][2]`.  However, in the next example:

```
matx.flatten!  # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
               #     9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

Now the element `7` is located at `matx[6]`.

So essentially, I'm looking for a way to, given the dimensions of the matrix and the set of indices for the particular element, convert from the stacked matrix to the flattened matrix.  <strike>Reverse would be awesome, too, but I figure the way to get that is similar (but essentially reversed) to the method of obtaining this result.</strike> I realized that reverse is not actually a function, because there's no way to necessarily tell the difference as to whether 5 maps to [2,3] or [3,2], etc.  So I'm not going to look into that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Index
  def initialize *dims
    @dims = dims.reverse
  end

  def if_flat *subs
    raise unless @dims && @dims.size == subs.size
    res = 0
    subs.reverse.each_with_index { |s, i| res += s * @dims[0...i].inject(1) { |m, e| m * e }}
    res
  end
end
puts Index.new(2, 2, 4).if_flat 0, 1, 2
```

Comment: This works great.  The only two things that confuse are
a) why did you reverse it? and
b) what is the bit with inject actually doing?

Comment: After a bit more inspection, I realize that it is essentially the same thing as `.reduce(:*)`.  Thanks for the help again! :)

Comment: Well, I wanted it to work with any number of dimensions, so I had to find a general solution. The `inject` expression just returns 1, or 1 x columns, or 1 x columns x rows, and so forth. It is computing the number by which each subscript will be multiplied, that is, the cumulative size of the objects the subscript is indexing over. Because the first subscript indexes the product of the dimensions of the remaining subscripts, it was convenient to process both dimensions and subscripts from right to left, hence the `.reverse`.